# swarmplot doesn't recognize hue when either the x or y parameter is omitted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
data = {'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'score': [-9.5, -8.3, -8.1, -7.0],
        'color': [4, 3, 2, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have my data in a dataframe like above and I am plotting it to a seaborn swarmplot like the one below. The points are plotted based on their score, and depending on how that falls between the 3 dotted lines, I want to color the points differently. I use the 'color' column of the df to assign a key based on where the 'score' values fall that corresponds to colors and a dictionary.

```
colors = {1:'pink', 2:'orange', 3:'red', 4:'green'}
```

I then create the swarmplot with the below code and map the color dictionary to the colors column of my df.

```
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df, y='score', s=10, c=df['color'].map(colors))
```

When I do this I don't generate any errors, but no colors are applied, and the points remain their default blue (image below, left). **So, how can I assign colors to points in a seaborn swarmplot based on my `df['color']` column?**

Final note: When I try to use `palette=df['color'].map(colors)` instead of `c=df['color'].map(colors)`, the graph just changes everything to the last color in my `colors` dictionary (image below, right)

[image]
[image]

Edit: Thank you for your suggestion @Trenton McKinney. It is somewhat successful in that the colors do properly map, but when I include the 'name' column (Its actually *Title*) for x, as below, my points are plotted like a scatter instead of a swarm plot. But I get an error if I try to remove `x='Title'` from my parameters.

```
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=data, x='Title', y='score', s=10, hue='color', palette=colors)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As per [seaborn issue 941](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/941), this is the expected behavior.
- Seems like the API doesn't play well when specifying only `x` or only `y`.

  - The issue is resolved by passing a list of the same strings based on the length of the dataframe: `['']*len(df)` or `['text']*len(df)`

```py
ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df, x=['']*len(df), y='score', hue='color', palette=colors)
```

[image]